# Relationships between tables in laravel using backpack package

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using [backpack CRUD](https://github.com/laravel-backpack/crud) package to create my website project in laravel 5.2

I want to establish a relationship between two tables. First table is called customer and second table is called transaction. Each customer has many transaction(1:N relationship).

Customer table record:

ID Name

123456 xyz

Transaction table record:

ID CustomerID

101010 123456

I know that I have to specify the relation in the customer model. But, how can I display the result of the relationship in CRUD ?

Answer (score 4):

You should have relationships on both the Transaction and the Customer models, so you can do `$customer->transactions` and `$transaction->customer`:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transactions', 'CustomerID', 'ID');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'CustomerID', 'ID');
    }
}
```

Spend some time in the [Eloquent Relationships Documentation](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). It's really important to understand them if you want to be a Laravel developer.

In order to display the relationship in the CRUD, you can then use Backpack's [select column type](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types#select) to display it in the table view and [select](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#select-1-n-relationship) or [select2](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#select2-1-n-relationship) field types to display it in the add/edit views. Read the [CRUD Example Entity](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-example) to better understand how that works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you are creating migrations for both tables, table which contain Foreign Key (FK) must have field like this:

```
public function up(){
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('customerID')->unsigned();
}
```

After that you are need to call next command into console

```
php artisan migrate
```

Next is going next commands:

```
php arisan backpack:crud customers
php arisan backpack:crud transactions
```

After that you need to define functions in models which returns values from other tables.  Customer models need to have next function

```
public function transactions(){
   return $this->hasMany('Transaction');
}
```

Transaction model must have next function

```
public function customer() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Customer');
}
```

Next you must add CRUD field in Customer controller to display 
transactions in select box.

```
$this->crud->addField([
   'label' => 'Transactions', // Label for HTML form field
   'type'  => 'select2',  // HTML element which displaying transactions
   'name'  => 'customerID', // Table column which is FK for Customer table
   'entity'=> 'customer', // Function (method) in Customer model which return transactions
   'attribute' => 'ID', // Column which user see in select box
   'model' => 'Transaction' // Model which contain FK
]);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

After you built onetomany relationship with transaction, you can get the results.

```
$customer=Customer::where(['id'=>'123456'])->with('transaction')
                                           ->first();

print_r($customer->Name);  // gives the customer name
foreach($customer->transaction as $cid)
{
     print_r($cid->CustomerID);       // gives the customer id
}
```

[Laravel Relationships Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) is always helpful. Go through it.